# Animating shapes in SFML?

Tags: animation, sfml

I just wanted to **animate a simple shape** (rect for instance). This animation is *only about changing the color of the shape whenever you press a determinated key*.

I couldn't find any tutorial for this simple purpose, these online tutorials are all about sprite movement and all of that.

I **managed to do this** color change by creating a class named 'Transition' and a function within it named 'Transition::update()', which simply change the color of a shape created in this class. The code it's quite simple (thought it wasn't necessary to put it here).
The problem is that this animated I created it's not a smooth animation, just change the color at the right moment.

The question is obvious:

> How could I give that smoothness to my animation?

(Don't need to put large codes here, just a quick advice that's all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to introduce variables which store the transition of the color and you need to control the time per frame. Let me give you a quick and very basic example, so you get the idea. Forgive me the style ...

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
  sf::RenderWindow renderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Color Animation");

  sf::Clock clock;
  sf::Event event;
  // Change to start the animation
  // Red and blue to store the color transition
  // Duration to control animation speed
  int change = 0;
  int red = 255;
  int blue = 0;
  float duration = float();

  // Set a basic red circle as the starting shape
  sf::Color color = sf::Color::Red;
  sf::CircleShape circle(150);
  circle.setFillColor(color);

  while (renderWindow.isOpen()){
    // How much time since last loop?
    sf::Time dt = clock.restart();
    duration += dt.asSeconds();

    while (renderWindow.pollEvent(event)){
      //Handle events here
      if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
        renderWindow.close();

      //Respond to key pressed events
      if (event.type == sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed){
        if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::C){
          // C key pressed, start animation
          change = 1;
        }
      }
    }

    // Animation started and animation duration per frame (0.01f) reached
    // Change color by 1 
    if (change == 1 && duration > 0.01f){
      red -= 1;
      blue += 1;
      if (red > 0){
        // Reset frame time and set new color for circle
        duration = 0;
        color = sf::Color(red, 0, blue);
        circle.setFillColor(color);
      } else {
        // Stop animation 
        change = 0;
      }
    }

    // Clear render window and draw circle
    renderWindow.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    renderWindow.draw(circle);
    renderWindow.display();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just what I needed